# Assigning global variables in python to a single variable or function?

Tags: python, global-variables, global, variable-assignment

I think I grasp why global variables have to be used to bind variables in and outwith functions. So if I call:

```
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

    def example():
        global x
        global y
        global z
```

I'll be able to alter x, y, z that are outside of the function.

However, is there a way to assign all of my needed global variables to something else and then calling them in one line.

I tried:

```
def global_var():
    global x
    global y
    global z
```

and then calling:

```
def example():
   global_var()
   x += 1
   etc
```

But this doesn't seem to work. or at least the code seems to meet the x variable first and throws up a before assignment error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the keyword global has method scope therefore when you call it inside global_var() they will be available for modifications inside it. However when you return from it into example(). Your global has no effect anymore therefor x is read only and you cannot modify its value. You must get rid of gloval_var()

```
def example():
   global x
   global y
   global z
   x += 1
```

However if I can recommend you. Don't use such method. Use a dictionary if  those variables are related somehow so you can sipmply do.

```
my_vars = {'x':0, 'y':0, 'z':0}
def example():
   my_vars['x'] += 1
```

In this case, dictionary does not need the keyword global in order to be modified. The reason behind this is that you are not assigning a new value but only modifying an existing object. If you write `x += 2` it means `x = x + 2` which will result in a new assignment, that results in `x` pointing to another value and this is not possible without `global`. However, if you modify my_vars, its memory address stays the same but only its data changes, since `dict` is a mutable value.

Comment: Ah right, the values are related, is calling global just generally more inefficient? And can dictionary values be continually updated in this way. As in later on if I cal my_vars["x"] += 2, would x now equal three (using above example).

Comment: yes, you don't need to call global on dictionaries. Efficiency should be trivial so both cases will probably not affect the computation but the code quality will be better on the second case. I updated the answer to explain a bit better why the dictionary does not need global.

Comment: Thanks very much. Great help.

Answer (score 0):

You could create function that modifies global variables:

```
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

def setGlobals(**vals):
    for key, value in vals.iteritems():
        globals()[key] = value

print x, z
setGlobals(x=5, z=3)
print x, z
```

output:

```
0 0
5 3
```